# How to pass HTML attribute value as parameter

Tags: jquery, html, parameters, attributes

I have the following **Javascript** function

```
function CallOfferRenderAction(productCode, providerCode)
{

}
```

I'm trying to send attribute's value onclick but I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: offercode is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Here is how I'm sending attribute's values.

```
<input type="button" value="View" class="viewbtn" onclick="CallOfferRenderAction(this.attr(offercode), this.attr(providercode))" offercode="ATT-COMP-DTV-PRM-ALL-INCL_SEPARATOR_ATT-COMP-HSIA-PLS-A" providercode="ATTv6">
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: provide few more html content, where are you setting offercode and providercode that you use in the html.

Comment: The `offercode` variable is not inscope of the JS being executed. If you meant to include it as a string, then you'll see `attr() is not a function` as that's a jQuery method, and `this` is a native Element

Comment: I think you just need to surround offercode and providercode with single quotes.

Comment: I would just pass "this" to your function, and then figure out the attributes from there.

Comment: @DavidP tried that and then I got `Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function at HTMLInputElement.onclick` error

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Any other way I can pass them to the function?

Comment: Yes - I added an answer for you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `offercode` variable is not in the scope of the JS which is executing. If you meant to include it as a string to reference the attribute on your `button` element, then you'll see a different error:

> attr() is not a function

This is because `attr()` is a jQuery method, and `this` refers to a native Element.

To fix this you can provide `this` to a jQuery object:

```js
function CallOfferRenderAction(productCode, providerCode) {
    console.log(productCode);
    console.log(providerCode);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="View" class="viewbtn" onclick="CallOfferRenderAction($(this).attr('offercode'), $(this).attr('providercode'))" offercode="ATT-COMP-DTV-PRM-ALL-INCL_SEPARATOR_ATT-COMP-HSIA-PLS-A" providercode="ATTv6">
```

However, a much better solution entirely would be to use unobtrusive JS to attach the events. If preferred you can use jQuery to do this.

Also, note that the attributes you're adding are completely non-standard and may cause unforeseen problems. When adding your own metadata to an element it's best to use `data` attributes, as that is what they are designed for. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.viewbtn').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    console.log($(this).data('offercode'));
    console.log($(this).data('providercode'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="View" class="viewbtn" data-offercode="ATT-COMP-DTV-PRM-ALL-INCL_SEPARATOR_ATT-COMP-HSIA-PLS-A" data-providercode="ATTv6">
```

Comment: Great Explanation. Will be using data attributes! +1

Comment: No problem, glad to help.